# How to assign and print in list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list

It returns None. How to assign to video_list the list values?

```
video_list = [print(video.title) for video in videos]
```

EDIT :
The process to get videos list is very long , that's why I asked for

Comment: Drop the `print`. You want to store a reference to `video.title`, not print its value to standard output.

Comment: Assign a list without the `print` and just `print` it afterwards...

Comment: Note: It is considered poor form to use a comprehension for side-effects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `print` returns `None`, you could use `or` to return the value after printing, but this is not recommended.

```py
video_list = [print(video.title) or video.title for video in videos]
```

It is better to first create the list, then print it after.

Answer (score 0):

You should not print. Just get the value `video.title` . So answer `video_list = [video.title for video in videos]`

Answer (score 0):

```
video_list = [video.title for video in videos]
```

You can't use print in a list comprehension. Now you will have all values in `video_list` and you can print it as a list to see the values `print(video_list)`

Answer (score 0):

It would be more readable to keep assigning and printing apart:

```
video_list = [video.title for video in videos]
print(*video_list, sep='\n')
```